# Using both INSERTED and DELETED from and OUTPUT

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my `UPDATE` query, I would like to store the `deleted` and `inserted` values into separate database tables.

So my query needs to look something like this:

```
UPDATE A_TABLE
  SET table_column = 'something'
    OUTPUT deleted.*
    INTO audit.deleted_content

    OUTPUT inserted.*
    INTO audit.inserted_content
  WHERE blah = 'something else'
```

However I am getting an issue in my second `INTO` keyword *(incorrect syntax near 'into')*. Is there a correct way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary table to hold the results and do your inserts after like so:

```
create table #audit (
    deleted_table_column varchar(32)
  , inserted_table_column varchar(32)
)

update A_table
  set table_column = 'something'
    output deleted.table_column, inserted.table_column
    into #audit
  where blah = 'something else'


insert into audit.deleted_content
select deleted_table_column from #audit;

insert into audit.inserted_content
select inserted_table_column from #audit;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BVSFRJ92976